# Copy formatted table from doc1 to doc2

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have the function below which takes a table from an Excel spreadsheet,  creates multiple arrays, formats a Word form and also modifies a Word document template to be used as an email when the from is complete.

I want to copy a table from the first Word document to the second at a bookmark location. I tried various methods. This last one I tried is supposed to select the first document, select the table and copy it to the second. It completes successfully, however it seems to take a cell from the Excel document.

```
objWord.Documents("C:\temp\DOC1.docm").Activate
objDoc.Tables(2).Range.Select
Selection.Copy
      
objWord.Documents(""C:\temp\DOC2.docm").Activate
Set bkRange = objDoc2.Bookmarks(bkProductionHistory).Range
bkRange.Paste
```

---

```
Function FnOpenWordDoc(LastProdHist() As Variant, LastProdHistRow As Long, FileToSave As String) As Variant

Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim objDoc2
Dim xPctComp As Long

Dim rRange As Word.Range        'MSword range  for Boook mark
Dim bkRange As Word.Range

Dim tblNew As Table             'Table Production History
Dim BkProdHist As String        'Bookmark varialble

Dim x, y, a, b  As Variant

    
BkProdHist = "BkProductionsHistory"                 'Production History Bookmark - Containes the complete productiosn histor in the first workd doc.


'bookmarks for the email document
bkUserName = "bkUserName"                           'bookmark Location for user name
BkVolume = "bkProductionVolume"                     'Bookmark Location for volume information in email
bkProductionDownload = "bkProductionDownload"       'Bookmark location for Download Link in email
bkProductionHistory = "bkProductionHistory"         'Bookmark location for Table copied from first word document
bkProductionSearch = "bkProductionSearch"           'Bookmark location for Production Seach
bkArchivePassword = "bkArchivePassword"             'Bookmark Locaion for Archive password


Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\temp\DOC1.docm", ReadOnly:=True)
Set objDoc2 = objWord.Documents.Open(""C:\temp\DOC2.docm", ReadOnly:=True)

'objWord.Visible = False
objWord.Visible = True


objDoc.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
objDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
"C:\temp\DATA.XLSM", _
ConfirmConversions:=False, _
ReadOnly:=True, _
LinkToSource:=True, _
AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
PasswordDocument:="", _
PasswordTemplate:="", _
WritePasswordDocument:="", _
WritePasswordTemplate:="", _
Revert:=False, _
Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\temp\DATA.XLSM;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:", _
SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `ProductionRequest$`", SQLStatement1:="", _
SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
objDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdLastRecord
objDoc.MailMerge.ViewMailMergeFieldCodes = wdToggle
'objDoc.MailMerge.Execute

If Dir(FileToSave) <> vbNullString Then
    Kill FileToSave
    'MsgBox "Deleted the file"
End If
    

   '***************Create New Table With Production History - this is t first word doc 
**********************
LastProdHistRow = LastProdHistRow + 6               ' Adding additional rows to production history table
Set rRange = objDoc.Bookmarks(BkProdHist).Range
Set tblNew = objDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=rRange, NumRows:=LastProdHistRow, NumColumns:=10)

objDoc.Tables(2).Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = "Date"
objDoc.Tables(2).Cell(3, 2).Range.Text = "Volume"
objDoc.Tables(2).Cell(3, 3).Range.Text = "Begin Bates"
objDoc.Tables(2).Cell(3, 4).Range.Text = "End Bates"
objDoc.Tables(2).Cell(3, 5).Range.Text = "Documents"
objDoc.Tables(2).Cell(3, 6).Range.Text = "Redactions"
objDoc.Tables(2).Cell(3, 7).Range.Text = "Pages"
objDoc.Tables(2).Cell(3, 8).Range.Text = "Images"
objDoc.Tables(2).Cell(3, 9).Range.Text = "Natives"
objDoc.Tables(2).Cell(3, 10).Range.Text = "Slip-Sheets"
objDoc.Tables(2).Cell(LastProdHistRow + 6, 4).Range.Text = "Totals"
'************** End - Create Table with Production History



'Begin************** Copy Production History Array to  Word Table *************************
'the loop only copies the first 10 columns of the array to the word table.

a = 4           ' The starting row of the table to begin copying data
For x = LBound(LastProdHist, 1) To UBound(LastProdHist, 1)
    b = 1
            For y = LBound(LastProdHist, 2) To UBound(LastProdHist, 2)
                If y <= 9 Then
                    Debug.Print x, y, LastProdHist(x, y)
                    objDoc.Tables(2).Cell(a, b).Range.Text = LastProdHist(x, y)
                    b = b + 1
                End If
            Next y
    a = a + 1
Next x

'End**************  Produciton History Array to Word table ****************************
 
  With objDoc.Tables(2)
    .Range.Font.Size = 8
    .Columns(2).Width = 40.5    'Date Column width
    .Columns(3).Width = 81      'Begin Bates Column width
    .Columns(4).Width = 81      'End Bates Colum width
    .Columns(5).Width = 55      'Documents Column width
    .Columns(6).Width = 55      'Redactions Column width
    .Columns(7).Width = 37      'Pages Column width
    .Columns(8).Width = 41      'Images Column width
    .Columns(9).Width = 41      'Natives Column width
    .Columns(10).Width = 62.5   'Slip-Sheet Column width
    .Rows(LastProdHistRow).Range.Font.Bold = True
    .Rows(3).Range.Font.Bold = True
    .Rows(3).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .Cell(LastProdHistRow, 5).Formula Formula:="=Sum(Above)"
    .Cell(LastProdHistRow, 6).Formula Formula:="=Sum(Above)"
    .Cell(LastProdHistRow, 7).Formula Formula:="=Sum(Above)"
    .Cell(LastProdHistRow, 8).Formula Formula:="=Sum(Above)"
    .Cell(LastProdHistRow, 9).Formula Formula:="=Sum(Above)"
    .Cell(LastProdHistRow, 10).Formula Formula:="=Sum(Above)"
    .Rows(LastProdHistRow).Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Rows(LastProdHistRow).Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
    .Rows.SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=-3.5, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
End With
 
objDoc.Tables(2).Columns(1).Select
Set ObjSelection = objWord.Selection
ObjSelection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
objDoc.Tables(2).Columns(2).Select
Set ObjSelection = objWord.Selection
ObjSelection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
objDoc.Tables(2).Columns(3).Select
Set ObjSelection = objWord.Selection
ObjSelection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
objDoc.Tables(2).Columns(4).Select
Set ObjSelection = objWord.Selection
ObjSelection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
objDoc.Tables(2).Columns(5).Select
Set ObjSelection = objWord.Selection
ObjSelection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=InchesToPoints(0.4), Alignment:=wdAlignTabDecimal, Leader:=wdTabLeaderSpaces
objDoc.Tables(2).Columns(6).Select
Set ObjSelection = objWord.Selection
ObjSelection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=InchesToPoints(0.4), Alignment:=wdAlignTabDecimal, Leader:=wdTabLeaderSpaces
objDoc.Tables(2).Columns(7).Select
Set ObjSelection = objWord.Selection
ObjSelection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=InchesToPoints(0.5), Alignment:=wdAlignTabDecimal, Leader:=wdTabLeaderSpaces
objDoc.Tables(2).Columns(8).Select
Set ObjSelection = objWord.Selection
ObjSelection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=InchesToPoints(0.5), Alignment:=wdAlignTabDecimal, Leader:=wdTabLeaderSpaces
objDoc.Tables(2).Columns(9).Select
Set ObjSelection = objWord.Selection
ObjSelection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=InchesToPoints(0.25), Alignment:=wdAlignTabDecimal, Leader:=wdTabLeaderSpaces
objDoc.Tables(2).Columns(10).Select
Set ObjSelection = objWord.Selection
ObjSelection.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=InchesToPoints(0.4), Alignment:=wdAlignTabDecimal, Leader:=wdTabLeaderSpaces
 
With objDoc.Tables(2)
    .Rows(2).Cells.Merge
    .Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "DOCUMENT PRODUCTION HISTORY"
    .Cell(2, 1).Range.Style = ("Heading 1")
    .Cell(LastProdHistRow, 4).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
    .Rows(LastProdHistRow - 2).Shading.ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
    .Rows(LastProdHistRow - 2).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = -553582797
End With




'Begin************** Setting up Email to send to  reqestor  *************************
'****
'**** objDoc2  has been opend for the this reason

Set bkRange = objDoc2.Bookmarks(bkUserName).Range
bkRange.Text = LastProdHist(LastProdHistRow - 6, 13)

Set bkRange = objDoc2.Bookmarks(BkVolume).Range
bkRange.Text = LastProdHist(LastProdHistRow - 6, 1)

Set bkRange = objDoc2.Bookmarks(bkProductionSearch).Range
bkRange.Text = LastProdHist(LastProdHistRow - 6, 10)

Set bkRange = objDoc2.Bookmarks(bkArchivePassword).Range
bkRange.Text = LastProdHist(LastProdHistRow - 6, 11)
    
Set bkRange = objDoc2.Bookmarks(bkProductionDownload).Range
bkRange.Text = LastProdHist(LastProdHistRow - 6, 12)

objWord.Documents("C:\temp\DOC1.docm").Activate
objDoc.Tables(2).Range.Select
Selection.Copy

objWord.Documents(""C:\temp\DOC2.docm").Activate
Set bkRange = objDoc2.Bookmarks(bkProductionHistory).Range
bkRange.Paste
   
'End**************** Setting up Email to send to  reqestor  *************************

 

   'Debug.Print FileToSave

objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    "C:\Temp\" & FileToSave, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
    OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
    wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
    IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:= _
    wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:= _
    True, UseISO19005_1:=False
'ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Temp\"


objDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.Close
'objDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
'objWord.Application.Quit
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is quite simple - you haven't qualified `Selection.Copy`. It should be `objWord.Selection.Copy`.

Better still just use:

```
objDoc.Tables(2).Range.Copy
objDoc2.Bookmarks(bkProductionHistory).Range.Paste
```

Comment: Jesus, i have been beating myself for the past 4 to 5 days on this!    Thank you!!!!  Timothy, i guess was over complicating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to activate either document. Furthermore, all you need for the replication is:

```
objDoc2.Bookmarks(bkProductionHistory).Range.FormattedText = objDoc.Tables(2).Range.FormattedText
```